# VBA SHORT EMAILS BY SENDER

Tags: vba, outlook

I just started using VBA and I am trying to launch the rules that I have thought python so I gave a try with the usual rule to short mails form someone and move that emails from inbox to another folder (in this case named zzz). Since I have three different accounts on outlook I want to do it for the account named myemail@company.com in the code.

```
Sub ResolveName()
 Dim ns As NameSpace
 Set ns = Application.Session
 Dim acc As Account
 Dim f As Folder
 Dim myDestFolder As Folder
 
 Dim myItem As Object

 For Each acc In ns.Accounts
    
    If acc = "myemail@company.com" Then
    Set f = acc.DeliveryStore.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
         
    Set myDestFolder = f.Folders("zzz")
    Set myItem = f.Items.Find("[SenderName] = 'SendersName Surname'")
    While TypeName(myItem) <> "Nothing"
        myItem.Move myDestFolder
        Set myItem = myItems.FindNext
    Wend

 End If
 Next
End Sub
```

When I run it, I get the following error

The following error has happened '-2147221233 (8004010f)' on execution time
No object found.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Which line of code gives an error? Did you try to run the code under the debugger line-by-line?

Anyway, the following line of code is not correct:

```
If acc = "myemail@company.com" Then
```

The account object is not a string to compare. You need to use the [Account.SmtpAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.account.smtpaddress) property which returns a string representing the Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP) address for the Account.

However, I've found a [similar issue](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/0acbed9c-de08-40f7-a77e-2cd0e626d9cb/outlook-data-file-cannot-be-accessed-error-8004010f?forum=outlook) which explains possible causes - the error number can tell us about a problem with a PST file (storage).

Comment: I have added MsgBox acc.UserName and MsgBox f.Items.Count to the code after Set f to check if it is working there and that part seems to be working fine. I can not see where the code fails. The error that I have mentioned is the only thing that I see. How do I run the debugger? Sorry I normaly only use python ,I am not very good at VBA

Comment: The problem can be related to a specific store. Try to create a new profile and see whether a problem still exist.